# How to trim the WHOIS disclaimer?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, text, text-formatting, whois

What's the best way to trim the massive disclaimer from the end of the `whois` output?

It looks something like this:

```
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2017-01-30T20:17:39Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

Access to Public Interest Registry WHOIS information is provided to 
assist persons in determining the contents of a domain name registration record 
in the Public Interest Registry registry database. 
The data in this record is provided by Public Interest Registry for informational 
purposes only, and Public Interest Registry does not guarantee its accuracy. 
This service is intended only for query-based access. 
You agree that you will use this data only for lawful purposes and that, under no 
circumstances will you use this data to(a) allow, enable, or otherwise support 
the transmission by e-mail, telephone, or facsimile of mass unsolicited, 
commercial advertising or solicitations to entities other than the data 
recipient's own existing customers; or (b) enable high volume, automated, 
electronic processes that send queries or data to the systems of Registry 
Operator, a Registrar, or Afilias except as reasonably necessary to register 
domain names or modify existing registrations. All rights reserved. 
Public Interest Registry reserves the right to modify these terms at any time. 
By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page:

```
       -H      Do not display the legal disclaimers some registries like to show you.
```

So.. `whois -H domain.example.com`?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't expecting that. I mean, technically, it does solve the specific question that I asked; I was actually anticipating/hoping for an alternative, portable (text manipulation style) method, that could be used with other tools as well, in similar situations. Do you know of anything like that?

Comment: quick and dirty:  `whois domain.example.com | grep '^ .*:'`